# Branch.io implement referral system

Tags: android, branch.io

I'm trying to implement branch.io referral system in my game.

I have some questions about branch.io

1. It is mandatory to  identify users on log in and log out, or if I don't want branch system will take care of this?
2. Before rewarding user in `onStateChanged` every time I need to check `changed` to be `true` ?
3. It is mandatory to set credits balance(on first start) and then use `redeemRewards` ?
4. How to implement own Filter after adding in reward rule and filter in dashboard  ?

My problem is that `onStateChanged` call me every time and on every device(referring and referred acting users), even my rule in dashboard is only  `Referred acting user` and even I add custom filter in dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaron from [Branch.io](https://google.com) here

**1. It is mandatory to identify users on log in and log out, or if I don't want branch system will take care of this?**
It's mandatory to identify the users if you want Branch to merge identities, otherwise random IDs may be tied to each referrer and referree since we don't merge them automatically. To acknowledge the referral and merge identities, you must call [setIdentity()](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-users) before you create a link in order to the referring users' identity to link itself. Once a referred user goes through the install process, you must call [setIdentity()](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-users) again before you [trigger an event](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/android/#track-events) that triggers the Reward Rule for the referree.

**2. Before rewarding user in onStateChanged every time I need to check changed to be true ?** If you are using `onStateChanged` to track the state of the referral and sign up, then yes you'd likely have to check if it's `true` to trigger the Reward Rule at that time. This will prevent the Reward Rule from triggering each time.

**3. Is it mandatory to set credits balance(on first start) and then use redeemRewards ?** No, it is not mandatory to set the credit balance on first start. Every identity will start off with a credit balance of zero and will increment or decrement only on redemption or the triggering of Reward Rules.

**4. How to implement own Filter after adding in reward rule and filter in dashboard ?** You definitely can implement filters on your Reward Rules. You can use the same filter parameters as you do for our webhooks system which you can find in 
the documentation [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/exports/webhooks/#filter-webhooks).

---

We highly recommend you set your Reward Rules to trigger on custom events and not `installs` and `opens` to avoid the unwanted merging of identities. You can always find more documentation on our referral mechanism [here](https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/referrals/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I implement all things except 4. I know how to add filter from dashboard, but I don't know how to implement this filter in android code. Witch android method should I use to enter this params? Can you please help me with this? Thanks